# Change Parent Jframe from Children : Panel inside JsplitPane

Tags: java, swing, sqlite, jframe, jsplitpane

I'm concentrated on my own project to manage a stock place , so i created an Gui using Java Swing in Netbeans- as the image showing -with a lot of library like( Flamingo , trident , SwingX_All .... etc )

### [image]

this Gui is related to Sqlite , the main Jframe contain ribbon menu and an horizontal JsplitPane with lift side and right side containing a vertical JsplitPAne in the top of it i added my Jpanel named AddArticles containing a button a insert data in Sqlite database and refresh jTable in  the bottom og the vertical JsplitPane

### [image]

My Problem is i can't refresh the table from the button event method  knowing that i tried to get the parent trying to change the parent component directly  ??

Comment: The basic problem is being able to reference the table model some how.  You could create the class hierarchy in such away that the table model becomes a property which needs to be passed between them in order to bind the views together.  This means that you could create the table model, provide a reference of it to the button, but then, either through constructors or setters, pass the reference of the model down to the view that actually needs it...as a possibility...

Comment: you mean that i must invoke a method in parent container from panel that contain the button

Comment: Nope, I mean you need to share a common object (the table model) between the button and the table.  If the table is buried by layers of components, you need to provide some means to pass that object down through them, either via the constructors or some kind of setter

Comment: This is the solution , i passed my main frame as parameter in the panel than i used it in the panel which contain the button than i invoke method in the main Frame :) , Thanks a lot @MadProgrammer

Comment: While it works, it's a bad idea, you've exposed to much information to a portion of the application that doesn't need to know it. This provides the ability for the panel to change the frame in ways it shouldn't be allowed to ... Like remove everything from the frame. While its a personal project, I'd always encourage the use of best practices

Comment: in reality , what i made is removing all component of the parent component of the panel (in this case the parent component is the right side of the main Jsplitpane ) and than i added the top and the bottom split like i made in first time i launch my Main Frame :) , Now it works very well :)